# VideoFrames are only coming when esc,spacebar or enter keys are pressed OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv3.2

I am kind of an intermediate in Computer Vison and fairly proficient in opencv python however coming to c++ i am facing problems in just selecting ROI from Video feed and displaying the cropped feed .My code looks like this.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
  #include "opencv2/tracking.hpp"
#include "iostream"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
 int main() {

Mat frame1;
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);
cap.read(frame1);
Rect2d roi = selectROI(frame1, true);
Mat Crop = frame1(roi);

while (1) {

    cap.read(frame1);
    Crop = frame1(roi);
    if (Crop.empty()) {
        cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
        break;

    }
    imshow("roi", Crop);
    int key=waitkey(0);

}
}
```

The code is compiling ,and the cropped window is seen however I am always in need to click enter,spacebar or esc to get the video feed.Weird?

Comment: I forgot to add there obviously needs to be a waitkey at the end duh!!

Comment: you can edit the question to correct the code, but this is most likely your issue - use `waitKey(1)` instead of `waitKey(0)`

Comment: Hey thanks that actually worked.....I didnt noticed that my keyboard was waiting for infinite keypresses...thought something was wrong with the logic..very silly,,thanks aton!!!

Answer (score 1):

So the correct version of the corrected code will look somewhat like this.Thanks for the help.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/tracking.hpp"
#include "iostream"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main() {

Mat frame1;
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);
cap.read(frame1);
 Rect2d roi = selectROI(frame1, true);
 Mat Crop = frame1(roi);

 while (1) {

cap.read(frame1);
Crop = frame1(roi);
if (Crop.empty()) {
    cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
    break;

}
imshow("roi", Crop);
*int key=waitkey(1)*;
```

}
}

Comment: please highlight the change made so it's easier to notice when someone comes by with similar issue and accept your own answer